# Importing a .xlsx file into models, receiving an Integer out of range error for the DateField: Line number: 1 - integer out of range

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am attempting to import a spreadsheet of video games into my Django database. I have set up the models with date fields, and I believe I have formatted my spreadsheet so that it matches with what Django is expecting.

I am using the Django import-export package. I have tried to manually set the formatting in the Django `settings.py` file, but that doesn't seem to fix it.

> models.py

```
from django.db import models
from multiselectfield import MultiSelectField
from django.urls import reverse


class Game(models.Model):

    boxArt = models.ImageField(default='questionmark.png', upload_to='boxart')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    genres = MultiSelectField(max_choices=5, choices=GENRES, blank=True)
    developers = MultiSelectField(max_choices=5, choices=DEVELOPERS, blank=True)
    platforms = MultiSelectField(max_choices=5, choices=PLATFORMS, blank=True)

    releaseDateJP = models.DateField(null=True,blank=True)
    releaseDatePAL = models.DateField(null=True,blank=True)
    releaseDateNA = models.DateField(null=True,blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
            return f'{self.title} Game'

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('game_detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

> settings.py

```
DATE_INPUT_FORMATS = ['%Y-%m-%d']
```

Here is what the first line of my spreadsheet looks like:
[image]

I expect for my models to be filled with the appropriate data; the release dates. But the first date field (`releaseDateJP`), is what I believe to be causing the error:

```
Errors:
Line number: 1 - integer out of range
None, None, &: Sora no Mukō de Saki Masuyō ni, None, Akatsuki Works, PLAYSTATION3, 2013-12-26 00:00:00, None, None
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\J\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 85, in _execute
return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
psycopg2.errors.NumericValueOutOfRange: integer out of range

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\J\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\import_export\resources.py", line 522, in import_row
self.save_instance(instance, using_transactions, dry_run)
File "C:\Users\J\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\import_export\resources.py", line 315, in save_instance
instance.save()
File "C:\Users\J\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 718, in save
force_update=force_update, update_fields=update_fields)
File "C:\Users\J\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 748, in save_base
updated = self._save_table(raw, cls, force_insert, force_update, using, update_fields)
File "C:\Users\J\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 831, in _save_table
result = self._do_insert(cls._base_manager, using, fields, update_pk, raw)
File "C:\Users\J\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 869, in _do_insert
using=using, raw=raw)
File "C:\Users\J\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py", line 82, in manager_method
return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
File "C:\Users\J\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1136, in _insert
return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
File "C:\Users\J\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1289, in execute_sql
cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "C:\Users\J\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 100, in execute
return super().execute(sql, params)
File "C:\Users\J\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 68, in execute
return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
File "C:\Users\J\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 77, in _execute_with_wrappers
return executor(sql, params, many, context)
File "C:\Users\J\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 85, in _execute
return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
File "C:\Users\J\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
File "C:\Users\J\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 85, in _execute
return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.DataError: integer out of range
```

Comment: Are you sure it's the date causing the error? Can you show stack trace?

Comment: I'm not sure what exactly a stack trace is, but is it the error I'm shown when I'm attempting to import it?

Comment: [Stack Trace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3988788/what-is-a-stack-trace-and-how-can-i-use-it-to-debug-my-application-errors), can you show the lines in the error? Also the rest of the fields in your model would help.

Comment: Updated my post with the other models fields, and stack trace

Comment: The first line of your error shows `None, None, &: Sora no Mukō de Saki Masuyō ni, None, Akatsuki Works, PLAYSTATION3, 2013-12-26 00:00:00, None, None`, looks like the releaseDateJP is going with time too (2013-12-26 00:00:00), maybe this is the problem. I suspect from the `MultiSelectField` as well, I never used it before, so not sure how it works, make sure to check the choices have the correct option for that first line.

Comment: Also one more thing to take note, checking the parameters again `None, None, &: Sora no Mukō de Saki Masuyō ni, None, Akatsuki Works, PLAYSTATION3, 2013-12-26 00:00:00, None, None`, the first value is `None`, it should be 2 from the picture you have linked, since the line has a number 2 on it.